# Mapping result rows to namedtuple in python sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, namedtuple

I am playing a bit with the python api for sqlite3, i have a little table for store languages with an id, name and creation_date fields. I am trying to map the raw query results into a `namedtuple` as the docs recommend, it that way i can manage rows in a more readable way, so here is my `namedtuple`.

```
LanguageRecord = namedtuple('LanguageRecord', 'id, name, creation_date')
```

The code that the docs suggest for the mapping is as follows:

```
for language in map(LanguageRecord._make, c.fetchall()):
  # do something with languages
```

This is fine when i want to return a collection of languages but in this case i want just
to retrieve one language:

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM language WHERE name=?', (name,))
```

So my first attempt it was something like this:

```
language = map(LanguageRecord._make, c.fetchone())
```

This code doesn't works because `fetchone()` returns a tuple instead a list with one tuple,
so the `map` function tries to create three `namedtuples` one for each tuple field thought.

My first approach to solve this was to explicitly create a list and append to it the tuple result, something like:

```
languages = []
languages.append(c.fetchone())
for language in map(LanguageRecord._make, languages):
  # do something with language
```

My second approach was to use `fetchall()` although i just want one record. I can set
the name field with a `unique` constrain in the database in order to garantize just one result.

```
for language in map(LanguageRecord._make, c.fetchall()):
  # do something with languages
```

Another approach could be use `fetchall()[0]` without the `unique` constrain to garantize just one result.

My question is which is the best and common way to deal with this problem, should i use always `fetchall` to maintain a common interface and let the database manage the uniqueness logic? or should i create a list explicitly as in approach 1? Is there a more easy way to accomplish this task?

Comment: You can also iterate over the database cursor, there's no need to fetch all the records, unless you want to, so the code can be rewritten as `map(LanguageRecord._make, c)`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There is a much easier way! Sqlite3 provides a way for the user to define ["row factories"](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.row_factory). These row factories take the cursor and the tuple row and can return whatever type of object it wants.

Once you set the row factory with

```
con.row_factory = my_row_factory
```

then rows returned by the cursor will be the result of `my_row_factory` applied to the tuple-row. For example,

```
import sqlite3
import collections

LanguageRecord = collections.namedtuple('LanguageRecord', 'id name creation_date')
def namedtuple_factory(cursor, row):
    return LanguageRecord(*row)

con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
con.row_factory = namedtuple_factory
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("select 1,2,3")
print(cur.fetchone())
```

yields

```
LanguageRecord(id=1, name=2, creation_date=3)
```

---

For another example of how to define a namedtuple factory, see [this post](http://peter-hoffmann.com/2010/python-sqlite-namedtuple-factory.html).

---

By the way, if you set

```
conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
```

then rows are returned as dicts, whose keys are the table's column names. Thus, instead of accessing parts of the namedtuple with things like `row.creation_date` you could just use the builtin `sqlite3.Row` row factory and access the equivalent with `row['creation_date']`.

Comment: `sqlite3.Row` is not a real dict, as it doesn't implement `.get()` or `.__contains__()`.

Comment: Your solution could be even more concise. With an active cursor you can set the row factory with the following one liner; `cursor.row_factory = lambda _, row: LanguageRecord(*row)`. I've used this pattern to create a wrapper class for a sqlite db that has several different return types.

Answer (score 10):

An improved `row_factory` is actually this, which can be reused for all sorts of queries:

```
from collections import namedtuple

def namedtuple_factory(cursor, row):
    """Returns sqlite rows as named tuples."""
    fields = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
    Row = namedtuple("Row", fields)
    return Row(*row)

conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
conn.row_factory = namedtuple_factory
cur = con.cursor()
```

Comment: what sets the cursor and row in the named_factory function.  I don't see these values being passed to the function

Comment: @GoldenLion `row` is a tuple with a single row's values. `Row(*row)` is where the values get passed to the named tuple that will be returned.

Comment: The row_factory points to the namedtuple_factory function. does the con.cursor invoke the point function?

Comment: The `row_factory` is used internally by the `sqlite3` module. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.row_factory

Comment: thanks, I realized that was the pattern

Answer (score 1):

There is another one `row_factory` on the top of `namedtuple`:

```
from collection import namedtuple

def namedtuple_factory(cursor, row, cls=[None]):
    rf = cls[0]
    if rf is None:
        fields = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
        cls[0] = namedtuple("Row", fields)
        return cls[0](*row)
    return rf(*row)
```

One can generalize further in order to use other class factories:

```
def make_row_factory(cls_factory, **kw):
    def row_factory(cursor, row, cls=[None]):
        rf = cls[0]
        if rf is None:
            fields = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
            cls[0] = cls_factory("Row", fields, **kw)
            return cls[0](*row)
        return rf(*row)
    return row_factory
```

These factory functions are useful for cases when all query results have same fields.

Examples:

1. `namedtuple_factory = make_row_factory(namedtuple)`
2. `import dataclass`

   `row_factory = make_row_factory(dataclass.make_dataclass)`
3. `pip3 install recordclass`

   `import recordclass`

   `row_factory = make_row_factory(recordclass.make_dataclass, fast_new=True)`

Here are some performance counters to compare different ways (debian linux, 64 bit, python 3.9).

Script for creation test database:

```
N = 1000000
conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE test
             (id int, x real, y real, p int, q int)''')
gen = ((i, random(), random(), randint(0,N), randint(0,N)) for i in range(N))
c.executemany("INSERT INTO test VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)", gen)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Default:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
c = conn.cursor()
%time res = [row for row in c.execute("SELECT id,x,y,p,q FROM test")]
conn.close()
print(N * sys.getsizeof(res[0]) // 1000000, 'Mb')

CPU times: user 971 ms, sys: 92.1 ms, total: 1.06 s
Wall time: 1.06 s
80 Mb
```

sqlite3.Row:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
c = conn.cursor()
%time res = [row for row in c.execute("SELECT id,x,y,p,q FROM test")]
conn.close()
# print(N * sys.getsizeof(res[0]) // 1000000, 'Mb')

CPU times: user 1.11 s, sys: 80.1 ms, total: 1.19 s
Wall time: 1.19 s
```

namedtuple:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Row = namedtuple("Row", "id x y p q")
conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
c = conn.cursor()
%time res = [Row(*row) for row in c.execute("SELECT id,x,y,p,q FROM test")]
conn.close()
print(N * sys.getsizeof(res[0]) // 1000000, 'Mb')

CPU times: user 1.89 s, sys: 71.8 ms, total: 1.96 s
Wall time: 1.96 s
80 Mb
```

namedtuple-based row factory:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
conn.row_factory = make_row_factory(namedtuple)
c = conn.cursor()
%time res = [row for row in c.execute("SELECT id,x,y,p,q FROM test")]
conn.close()
print(N * sys.getsizeof(res[0]) // 1000000, 'Mb')

CPU times: user 1.93 s, sys: 116 ms, total: 2.05 s
Wall time: 2.05 s
80 Mb
```

recordclass:

```
from recordclass import make_dataclass
Row = make_dataclass("Row", "id x y p q", fast_new=True)
conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
c = conn.cursor()
%time res = [Row(*row) for row in c.execute("SELECT id,x,y,p,q FROM test")]
conn.close()
print(N * sys.getsizeof(res[0]) // 1000000, 'Mb')

CPU times: user 1 s, sys: 72.2 ms, total: 1.08 s
Wall time: 1.07 s
56 Mb
```

recordclass-based row factory:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
conn.row_factory = make_row_factory(make_dataclass, fast_new=True)
c = conn.cursor()
%time res = [row for row in c.execute("SELECT id,x,y,p,q FROM test")]
conn.close()
print(N * sys.getsizeof(res[0]) // 1000000, 'Mb')

CPU times: user 1.11 s, sys: 76.2 ms, total: 1.19 s
Wall time: 1.19 s
56 Mb
```

Answer (score 0):

I demonstrate how to take a resulting dataframe from a sql query and convert it into a namedtuple list.  I did not dynamic bind the dataframe columns to the nametuple names, not sure if this is possible.

```
LanguageRecord=namedtuple('Generic',['id','name','creation_date'])
def map_to_language_record(row):
    return LanguageRecord(row.id, row.name, row.creation_date)

df=pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3],'name':['bob','dick','jane'],'creation_date': 
  ['1/1/2021','1/2/2021','1/3/2021']})

languages = list(map(map_to_language_record, df.itertuples()))
print(languages)
```

output:

```
[Generic(id=1, name='bob', creation_date='1/1/2021'), Generic(id=2, name='dick', creation_date='1/2/2021'), Generic(id=3, name='jane', creation_date='1/3/2021')]
```

Answer (score -2):

I think better to use 
`for language in map(LanguageRecord._make, c.fetchall()[:1]):`
Because it can cause IndexError with fetchall()[0].

If you need one result and there is already "WHERE"  in query. As I understand query should return one row. Early optimization is evil. :)